# Changing from KeyListener to TextWatcher

Tags: android, textwatcher

My app only consists of a textfield, where as soon as "1" is pressed on it, "Hello, world" to be further written on it. I used:

```
et.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1)) {
            et.setText("Hello, world!");
            current_string = et.getText().toString();
            length = current_string.length();
            et.setSelection(length);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

But I'd like to use a TextWathcer instead. I'd use:

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            //if statement here I guess
            et.setText(et.getText() + "Hello, world");
        }
    });
```

But am I having some problems finding the if statement. Can you please give me some hints? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you input '1' key, you wanna show 'Hellow World' on the TextView. Is that right?

```
@Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

     //if statement here I guess
     et.setText(et.getText() + "Hello, world");
}
```

Editable s will be returned the text that you input on Textfield. I think if you use just TextViews,

Upper one will be better way to solve it. I want to help you, figure it out together!!

UPDATE 1 :

```
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      if(s.toString().equals('1')){
           et.setText(s.toString() + "Hello, world");
      }
      //et.setText(et.getText() + "Hello, world");
 }
```

UPDATE 2 :

```
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      if(s.toString().contains("1")){
           et.setText(s.toString().replace("1", "Hellow World"));
      }
      //et.setText(et.getText() + "Hello, world");
 }
```

I hope it will work well.

Comment: I mean, "1" should just write "Hello, World" on the textfiend, instead of "1". For example, on a clear field, "2" is pressed and gives "2" on it. Then, "1" is pressed and gives "2Hello, World" :)

Comment: Textfield means EditText? or TextView? i guess EditText :D

Comment: it means EditText, yeap

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work. 1 gives 1 as normal :'( really thanks for your help tho

Comment: finally I got it! so sorry. I put the wrong answer before. last one, plz try it!

Comment: it worked, nice! I made up a long and sloppy solution before but yours looks much more nice and small. big, big thanks for your help man :D